# Syntax issue with tso function in tsoutliers package

Tags: r, syntax, time-series, outliers, arima

I have a data frame (3575 observations long) with two columns, Date and Oxygen Concentration. Date is in YYYY-MM-DD format for 25 years and oxygen values are numbers running anywhere from 0.05 to 7.5. I'm trying to locate outliers in my dataset using the tsoutliers package and my problem is with the syntax and not the values of the data themselves.

I first used the auto.arima function with this code:

```
auto.arima(Site7$Oxygen, seasonal = TRUE, stepwise = FALSE)
```

I'm sorry about not being able to give a minimum reproducible example but given the scale of the data and tests, it would be quite difficult to put it all in here.

For the results I got:

```
Series: Date$Oxygen  
ARIMA(3,1,2) 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2     ar3      ma1      ma2
      0.2988  0.2439  0.1431  -0.4348  -0.5259 
s.e.  0.0947  0.0686  0.0316   0.0948   0.0772

sigma^2 estimated as 0.5999:  log likelihood=-4145.53 
AIC=8303.06   AICc=8303.09   BIC=8340.15
```

Now, as I'm trying to visualize Additive Outliers I used the tso() command with this code:

```
AOoutliers <- tso(Date$Oxygen,types = "AO", maxit = 10, tsmethod = c("arima"), args.tsmethod = list(order =c(3,1,2)))
```

I now have this error which I can't seem to figure out:

> Error in tso0(x = y, xreg = xreg, cval = cval, delta = delta, n.start
>   = n.start, : trying to get slot "y" from an object of a basic class ("numeric") with no slots

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i think it might be a problem with your date. check the structure of your Date variable it might be numeric. use str() to check the structure , if it is Numeric convert it to date using library(lubridate)  and ymd(Date) this will convert your  variable to date format .

Comment: @Hunaidkhan The date is already a Date variable, so this isn't the issue. Thank you for trying to help nonetheless. :)

Comment: The input data passed through argument `y` must be a `ts` object. It seems there is some issue with the format of the data. `class(Date$Oxygen)` should return `ts`. Check it out or post 
the output from `dput(head(Date$Oxygen))`.

Comment: @javlacalle thank you, this is exactly what I need!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error with tsoutliers package using Nile dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323636/syntax-error-with-tsoutliers-package-using-nile-dataset)