# Syntax error with tsoutliers package using Nile dataset

Tags: r, syntax, time-series, syntax-error, outliers

I'm trying to locate outliers in a time series using the tsoutliers package.

I'm using the classic Nile dataset (which you can find here: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html) and I'm unsucessfully getting the tso() function to work.

My code is:

```
nile.outliers <- tso(Nile,types = c("AO","LS","TC"))
```

However, I get this syntax error, or what I assume is a syntax error:

> Error in tso0(x = y, xreg = xreg, cval = cval, delta = delta, n.start = n.start,  : 
>     trying to get slot "y" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object

If anyone can help me figure out this problem that would be amazing! Thanks!

Comment: what's `class(Nile)` like? it's working for me, can you share details of your `sessionInfo()`? Also please include the library for `tso`, I'm assuming `tsoutliers`, in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quibble:  that's not a syntax error (which would come from R), it's a run-time error from the `tso0` function in the `tsoutliers` package.

But from your description of where to get the data, it looks as though you are passing in a data frame, when `tso` wants a `"ts"` object.  You don't need to download the data, it's built in to R; so you remove the bad one you created, and use the built-in one:

```
rm(Nile)
nile.outliers <- tso(Nile,types = c("AO","LS","TC"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!